# How to enable usb debugging with locked screen in Samsung Galaxy A51?

Tags: adb, samsung, usb-debugging

I forgot my pattern to unlock my phone and I rebooted it, so no way to use finger print or facial recognition. I want to remove the gesture.key file with adb command but USB debugging option needs to be on.
Is there any way to enable USB debugging with the screen locked ?

Comment: Deleting the `gesture.key` does only work on old Android devices as far as I know. What Android version is installed on your Samsung A51?

Comment: @Robert oh I didn't know, it's android 11

Comment: if you forgot your pattern the only other way to unlock is remote https://findmymobile.samsung.com any other by-pass method you find will not work or erase all data

Comment: @alecxs the airplane mode is activated so findmymobile doesn't work, and I can't inactivate it without unlocking the phone

Comment: long press power button and disable airplane mode (no unlocking needed)

Comment: @alecxs nope you can't do it on this phone, all I can do is reboot it.

Comment: then factory reset and unlock with google account afterwards